# Что означает знак вопроса в параметрах XML-разметки

Tags: android, xml

Подскажите, что означает символ "?" в значении атрибута style?

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Означает [ссылку на атрибут стиля](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes) в текущей примененной теме.